# nestjs prisma tring to create new user but fails with dto object

Tags: typescript, postgresql, swagger, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a new user using `DTO` but it fails, but when im creating a user without the dto but by passing the values in the body it succeeds.

All other routes work but anything that uses dto doesent, altough yesterday everything was working fine until i started working on auth and installed few packages and now it doesent work, wasnt using git so cant go back.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ero.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldvm7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyH6C.png)

```
  @Post()
  create(@Body() { username, password, email }) {
    console.log(1)
    return this.usersService.create({ username, password, email });
  }

  async create({ username, email, password }) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(
      password,
      roundsOfHashing,
    );

    password = hashedPassword;

    return this.prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email
      }
    });
  }
```

Auth does work and i can login and get token but cant create or update item or user

Comment: Please try to provide minimum reproduction code / or code for other ppl to understand problem and avoid sharing images whenever possible.

What error do you get? What do you mean by it does not work now?

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: found my problem i didnt add class-validatoror and apipropertys to my dto